# Find incidence of new text in column and insert page break

Tags: excel, vba

This case is a bit tricky to explain, but I'll try. I want to make a sub that finds the the first incidence of a text in a column called Buffer ID (in this case, the first buffer is called 0.1N-HCl), and then finds new text in the column (values not = 01.N HCl) and inserts a page break between the first cell and second cells, so that it looks like this (highlights aren't needed in code):
[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzTm6.png)


Here's the code I have so far, but it doesn't function entirely. The code only works up to `Range(FirstBuffer, FirstBuffer.End(xlDown)).Select`

```
Sub PageSetup_PageBreaks_Buffers()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim BufferID As Range
Dim FirstBuffer As Range
Dim SecondBuffer As Range

Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Sheet 1")
Application.PrintCommunication = False

With WS
    ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
    'Resets all page breaks
    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
    'Shows page break preview
End With

Set BufferID = WS.Cells.Find(What:="Buffer ID", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    'Find column with Buffer ID header

With BufferID
Set FirstBuffer = BufferID.Offset(1)
'Find first buffer name under Buffer ID header
    With FirstBuffer
    Range(FirstBuffer, FirstBuffer.End(xlDown)).Select
    'Select column data below first buffer
        With Selection
            If FirstBuffer Is Nothing Then
            'Find first incidence of second buffer
            Set SecondBuffer = FirstBuffer.Offset(1)
                With SecondBuffer
                SecondBuffer.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

I'm stuck and not sure how to finish the execution. The code must be independent of the actual buffer ID names; 0.1N HCl and 1X-PBS-pH7.4 are just examples of buffer names that could be in the sheet. Any tips on how to finish this code, or suggestions for another more streamlined way to execute this function?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub PageSetup_PageBreaks_Buffers()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim BufferID As Range
    Dim c As Range, rngBuffers As Range, i As Long

    Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Sheet 1")


    WS.ResetAllPageBreaks 'Resets all page breaks

    'Find column with Buffer ID header
    Set BufferID = WS.Cells.Find(What:="Buffer ID", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not BufferID Is Nothing Then
        Application.PrintCommunication = False
        Set rngBuffers = WS.Range(BufferID, WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, BufferID.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        For i = 2 To rngBuffers.Cells.Count
            Set c = rngBuffers.Cells(i)
            If c.Value <> c.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
                c.EntireRow.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
            End If
        Next i
        Application.PrintCommunication = True
        ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview 'Shows page break preview
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Works great! Is there a way to ammend the code so it doesn't add a page break before the first buffer? When I execute the code, it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/0UCtG7Y

Comment: I tried playing with ```i =```, to no avail. Now I'm trying to see if I can add a line of code to delete the extraneous page break before the first buffer.

Comment: I got it to function with ```WS.HPageBreaks(2).Delete``` which takes out the extraneous page break. Thanks again Tim, you're the best!!